# Creating VR mobile application using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile, virtual-reality

I made my search and found that i can use [react vr](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/), when i try to deploy the code to android mobile, i found that it is for web only as shown here https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/publishing.html.

Is there any way i can build this react vr code to mobile? and if there isn't can i build vr mobile application using another javascript framework?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know React VR is web only. If you want to develop apps for mobile, other than VR, you can check out [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

You may also try creating a web app with React VR and running it in your mobile web browser.

Answer (score 0):

As Artur says, React Native is usually the way to go if you are targeting mobile.

There are some existing React Native VR libraries you can look at, for example:

- https://github.com/estate/react-native-vr

Its worth noting, however, that React VR (i.e. not the native flavour) claims to work in a browser on a mobile phone also:

> React VR does not, however, require a VR headset to run - it can also be used to create interactive 360 experiences that run in the browser or on a mobile phone.

from: https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/react-vroverview.html